# run a thread behind activities in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

Im developing for an android aplication and I need to run a thread in the background that is going to be check the current gps and show an activity depending of the current location data but the application have diferents activities, and I need this thread running all the time no matter if I change between an activity and other.
Can I do that ?
I know that I can add threads to an activity but I dont know how have a main thread in the background

Comment: Ever heard about Android [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Service which is not tied to any particular Activity. You can read all about Services [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

In your case I ssuggest you take a look at IntentService which automatically generates a background thread for you

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a service here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

You can run things in a background thread if you want in the service. And then you can bind to  it within your activites to communicate between the service and activities.